# How to crop output from the 5MP RPi v1 camera

Tags: libcamera

I'm scanning QR codes with a RPi Zero and a RPi camera v1 (5 MP, ov5647 sensor).

The camera has a fixed focus, which means that QR codes closer than about 40-50cm tends to become fuzzy because of the lack of focus. On the other hand, the QR codes are about 4-5cm on each side which at 40cm is relatively small and hard to scan.

I can ask libcamera2 for the maximum sensor resolution, 2592x1944, and only look for QR codes in the middle of the image. That *does* result in scannable QR codes, but is also very slow because of the amount of data transferred all the way from the sensor to my program.

The obvious fix is to crop earlier in the pipeline. Unfortunately, neither [VIDIOC_S_CROP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/vidioc-g-crop.html#c.VIDIOC_S_CROP) nor [VIDIOC_S_SELECTION](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/vidioc-g-selection.html#c.VIDIOC_S_SELECTION) are supported by libcamera.

Is there another way, other than switching to a variable focus camera?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is no apparent speedup from cropping at the libcamera2 level. Asking for the full resolution and cropping the resulting frames turned out fast enough, even on a Raspberry Pi Zero.